# Azure automation cannot pass parameters to powershell script inside VM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I can use azure automation runbook(powershell) to run a Powershell residing in the VM. It works well as long as there is no parameters required by the VM Powershell. If we send parameters from the runbook to VM powershell then it is not working. VM powershell recieves parameters as null. Runbook has no issues otherwise.
This is how parameter is passed.

```
$runcmdparameters=
@{"name" = "EXE"}

Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -AsJob -ResourceGroupName $RG-Name -Name $myName-CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1 -Parameter $runcmdparameters -Verbose
```

This is how the parameter is received in the VM-powershell-script

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$name
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my validation, you just need to pass a Hashtable variable into the run command parameters `-Parameter`, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-5.2.0#parameters).

Here is a working sample for your reference:

```
function Install-Postgres {

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$name
)
     
Write-Host "This is a sample script with parameters $name"

}

$ScriptToRun = Get-Content Function:\Install-Postgres

Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1

$params = @{"name"="EXE" }

$ss=Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMName $VMVame -ScriptPath "ScriptToRun.ps1" -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -Parameter $params
Write-output $ss.Value[0].Message
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look any different to the originally posted code so I guess there must be some other issue

Comment: Actually it does. The script(function) is part of automation script. While the OP had put that in the VM as a powershell file. Passing parameters to that caused issue. This is not solving that problem but this is a better solution for the OP.